# postgresql / postgis : low disk space

Tags: postgresql

Im trying to run a query on two tables on my postgresql database.

The query is like this :

```
psql -d gis -c "create table hgb as (select osm.*, h.geometry from osm_polygon osm join hautegaronne h on ST_contains(h.geometry,osm.way));"
```

The osm table is 1.3G rows and the h table is 1 row.

I get the error:

```
"CAUTION: Connection terminated due to crash of another server process
DETAIL: The postmaster instructed this server process to roll back the transaction
running and exiting because another server process exited abnormally
and that there is probably corrupted shared memory.
TIP: In a moment, you should be able to reconnect to the database.
data and relaunch your order.
the connection to the server was cut unexpectedly
The server may have terminated abnormally before or during the
request processing.
the connection to the server has been lost"
```

And my linux is showing me a notification "the / volume has only 438,2Mo of free disk space".

The postgresql log file tells :

```
ERROR: Could not write block 16700650 to file 'base/16384/486730.127': No space available on device
```

I have tried to set `temp_file_limit 10000000` in postgresql.conf but it didnt change anything.

Could I set an external hard drive as a temp folder for postgresql to process my query?
Can I set a cap limit for the temp file size?

Thank you

Comment: To me, this does not look related to programming. Maybe you could migrate your question to superuser.com?

Comment: @NicoHaase No, DBA Stackexchange would be appropriate.

Comment: If your `h` table contains only one row, what happens when you hardcode the geometry of that row into the query using a WHERE clause?

Comment: You are assuming that lack of disk space is the problem. Do you have any basis for that assumption? What does the PostgreSQL log tell you?

Comment: on a side note, storing the h polygon along every intersecting osm polygon sounds like a waste of resources.

Comment: thanks for your comments. how can i hardcode the geometry in the sql query? with ST_GeometryFromText(mygeometry,27572))? how would the where clause look like?